# Load all tiles for area in mapView

Tags: ios, swift, caching, mapkit, offline

I have found a way to cache tiles with MapKit, but I haven't found any solution for loading all tiles inside an area to from the top level tiles to the bottom level tiles.

I want to cache all tiles for a rectangle area in my mapview. Is there any way to do this in Mapkit?

Comment: please share the code that you tried

Answer (score 1):

In order to load custom tiles in `MKMapView` you need to subclass `MKTileOverlay` and override method
`url(forTilePath path: MKTileOverlayPath) -> URL`

`MKTitleOverlay` contains x, y and z properties for the tile.
So the implementation may look like this:

```
override func url(forTilePath path: MKTileOverlayPath) -> URL {
  let tilePath = Bundle.main.url(
  forResource: "\(path.y)",
  withExtension: "png",
  subdirectory: "tiles/\(path.z)/\(path.x)",
  localization: nil)!
  return tile
}
```

In your `mapView` setting function add the following:

```
let overlay = CustomTileOverlay()
overlay.canReplaceMapContent = true
mapView.add(overlay, level: .aboveLabels)
```

Also don't forget to return renderer in

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
  return MKTileOverlayRenderer(tileOverlay: overlay)
}
```

P.S. There is a great tutorial on [raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/158175/advanced-mapkit-tutorial-custom-tiles) on that subject:

Comment: Your answer didn't respond directly to my question, but you linked an article giving me hints on how I could at least get further on my challenge ;) Thank you!